# Unknown module Data.List in psci

Tags: purescript

I installed purescript with brew

```
$ brew install purescript
```

No problems there. when i boot up the PSCI repl and do this:

```
import Data.List
```

I get

```
Error in module $PSCI:
Unknown module Data.List
```

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I started up `psci` with `pulp`

```
$ pulp psci
```

Now when I try to import `Data.List` I get:

```
  Cannot unify type
    Control.Monad.Eff.Eff
  with type
    Prim.Function
```

Wtf?

**UPDATE**

Reinstalled purescript with npm

```
$ npm install -g purescript pulp
```

same problem. HELP.

Comment: Did you install `purescript-lists` using Bower or any other means? If so, did you load its modules into PSCi? If not, maybe read [this](http://www.purescript.org/learn/getting-started/) to get a working dev environment set up.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Start from a fresh REPL. Type `import Data.List`, and you should be fine. You might find [this](http://www.purescript.org/learn/getting-started/) helpful too.

Comment: even in a fresh REPL i get the same error `Cannot unify type`. The link you posted doesnt help.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are missing the [purescript-lists](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-lists) package.

Using pulp you can do the following:

```
mkdir myProject
cd myProject
pulp init
pulp dep install purescript-lists
pulp psci
> import Data.List
> toList [1,2,3]
Cons (1) (Cons (2) (Cons (3) (Nil)))
```

Comment: Now that it's 6 years later, the equivalent answer is probably `spago install lists`

Comment: @cvkline Worked for me just now (nov 2023)

Answer (score 4):

`bower install purescript-lists`

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm replying to an old question here but I've encountered the same problem and the solution above did not work for me. What did work for me was to add "purescript-lists": "^1.0.0" to bower.json and run "bower up".